# Mapping AltGr+t key as a Ctrl+x (How to use AltGr key effectively in Emacs)

Tags: key-bindings, x11

I am using international keyboard and extensively use <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key. There are many unused keys with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> so I would like to map <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> = <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. I don't want to remap <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to <kbd>Crtl</kbd>; I just want to use  this specific instance.

I am using debian with Gnome. May I map this combination with xkb?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do it from inside Emacs, you have to remap AltGr+T to a distinctive key at the xmodmap/XKB level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check what emacs gets when you hit AltGr+t. You can do so by invoking `C-h c AltGr+t`. With my keyboard configuration, this is ŧ (a character).

You can then `(global-set-key (kbd "ŧ") ctl-x-map)`.

In the event that you don't get a character, or that it is a too common character (e.g. 't' itself), you'll first want to configure your system with xmodmap to change that.

Comment: This works and runs without problem.